# Politely asking for a different laptop

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, communication

My employer has given me a new laptop (Windows) with good specs, but it has been too slow. At home I use a Mac and I think I would be more productive with one at work.  The office uses Windows because of knowledge of other senior colleagues who do the setup and managing database.

The boss told me on my first day that restriction of software and unavailability of tools are also a factor, but I know that all the software we use is available on the Mac as well.

How can I ask for a Mac laptop while not sounding bad or making him or myself look bad?

Comment: @Nofel I made an edit based on your comments.  If I misunderstood anything, please [edit] further.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This request would be likely to be denied and make you look bad. It would be preferable to ask for an upgrade to the Windows laptop. If you complain about not being able to use the core tools provided to do your job, they may start evaluating how much you're worth to them instead of replacing the core tools.

Using a Windows machine is not always an arbitrary decision, many workplaces will have a Windows domain server, Microsoft Certified Professionals administering them and the domain, bulk discounts on machines, homogeneous hardware for easy repair/replacement, and a host of other valid reasons not to have a Mac (or even a different brand of Windows laptop) attached unless it is doing a specific job that makes sense in a business context.

Your request may need to go to several people rather than be a simple matter of purchasing a machine. Techs to see if it's viable and set the machine up, purchasing people to find one and buy it, management to discuss everything etc,.

Comment: The OP has an extremely strong business case for a laptop that works, and works fast enough. That risks getting lost and ignored if the OP tries to turn it into a case for a Mac.

Comment: What business case? If the machine is crashing their IT should be looking at it as a totally normal procedure. Same if it's too slow. It's not even a business case for a new machine yet. My clients get requests like this all the time for new machines, probably >90% of them I just fix the machine and don't make any recommendation to replace. For a Mac I'd just laugh (very few Macs in my country, no one stocks them).

Comment: The way of getting to a laptop that works, and works fast enough, is a matter for IT. Personally, I would start by investigating the crashes, because some crash causes can also slow things down.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan good, we're in agreement then

Comment: @Kilisi thnx for ur answer. Though i had 6 yrs old mac, it wasn't slow as latest windows laptop.

Comment: @Nofel I find that _very_ hard to believe. "Windows laptop" isn't even a thing - you have several different models of hardware for any given year, and all of them are the "latest". A 300$ bucks laptop from 2017 running windows can't compare to a 3K mac from a few years ago. A 3k windows machine from the same year _obliterates_ the mac in performance. It depends.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you already discussed it with your boss.

> The boss told me on my first day that restriction of software and
>   unavailability of tools are also a factor, but I know that all the
>   software we use is available on the Mac as well

If you boss says it, then it is true.  End of story.  Let it go.  Continuing to push it is not going to be a good career move.

Also, your Mac might also be slow once they layer all the corporate security on it.  I suspect your laptop at home doesn't have to have things like drive encryption and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to make a business case.

What are the problems you're experiencing? How does that impact the company?

What are the available solutions? Pros, Cons, Cost Analysis for each. And which option you recommend.

---

In your case, you should probably suck it up and deal with a slightly slow Windows computer.